# Powershell Search Through Directory Tree with a combination of patterns

Tags: powershell

I need to search through a directory tree with certain patterns by Powershell. How should I put all patterns together so poweshell will search through the directory tree recursively.

Starting point: F:\Production

Patterns:

1. Any Child folder from starting point named as "Archive" will be
   excluded.
2. If child folder "All" exists then find child folder "POM" in there if exists.
3. Then find child folder name exactly starts with "PML" ends with "PROD" (PML****PROD) if exists from number 2.
4. Then find child folder "xml" if exsits from number 3.
5. Output all xml files in number 4 except "00.xml" file with file name and full path.

Loop through the whole directory tree from starting point with this pattern combination.

```
Starting Point:    F:\Production

F:\Production
|---AAA
|    |___Archive
|    |___80186
|         |___All
|              |___POM
|                |___xxx
|                |     |___PML*****PROD
|                |         |___XML
|                |              |___00.XML
|                |              |___01.XML
|                |              |___02.XML  
|                |___yyy
|                   |___PML*****PROD
|                         |___XML
|                              |___00.XML
|                              |___01.XML
|                              |___02.XML
|___BBB
|___CCC
|___DDD
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already determined the steps (the "algorithm" to use.)

Now, just use the pipeline to implement them :)

```
$XMLFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootDir -Filter "POM" -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.Parent.Name -eq 'All' -and $_.FullName -notlike "*\Archive\*"
} | Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "PML*PROD" | Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter "XML" | Get-ChileItem -Filter "*.xml" | Where {$_.Name -ne "00.xml"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just wondering why you start filtering from "POM", How can I do the "match" starting from root recursively. Your code stopped at "notlike \Archive\*", because I missed one level in the directory tree.

Comment: I start with "POM" because it's easy to determine if it's valid or should be ignored (parent must be "All" and full path not contain an "Archive" dir). I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem